# Ruby on Rails - Upload de arquivos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

atualmente possuo um requisito de permitir ao usuário efetuar upload de arquivos PDF e DOCX em minha aplicação com limite de tamanho. Como posso desenvolver esta funcionalidade utilizando o Rails?

Os arquivos físicos serão salvos na nuvem da AWS, e desejo somente manter as informações do arquivo no meu banco de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias gems que ajudam muito:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

https://gorails.com/episodes/file-uploading-with-carrierwave

http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/files/doc/direct_s3_md.html

https://gorails.com/episodes/file-uploading-with-shrine

https://gorails.com/episodes/direct-file-uploads-to-s3-part-3

https://github.com/refile/refile

https://gorails.com/episodes/file-uploads-with-refile

É questão de escolher a que te parecer mais adequada, no fim, todas operam mais ou menos parecido.